# How to restrict access to AWS NLB?

Tags: authentication, amazon-iam, amazon-elb, nlb, aws-nlb

- Service A: I have some AWS resources sitting behind a AWS NLB.
- Service B: Calls the endpoints exposed by the AWS NLB of Service A. This service has all the authentications that are required.

I have however run into an issue,

If a malicious user is able to break into Service B, due to the implicit trust that Service A places on the authentication of Service B, Service A will let the malicious user call its APIs. I want the following to mitigate this issue,

> Only Service B should be able to call the APIs exposed  by Service A.

Normally this should be fairly easy using IAM roles/policies but I guess NLB is not meant for the use case I have i.e. letting only a selected service call it. I guess NLB is designed such that anyone should be able to call it. Is there any way of achieving this form of service to service communication?

PS: I know this can be done if we use AWS ALB and AWS Classic LB as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/infrastructure-security.html) because both of these work at the request level, but NLB works at the connection level (transport layer) of the OSI model.

> Configure the security groups for your Application Load Balancers and Classic Load Balancers to accept traffic only from specific clients. These security groups must allow inbound traffic from clients on the listener ports and outbound traffic to the clients.

Comment: What is the difference between Service B and an attacker who breaks into, and controls, Service B?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AWS ALB and have your NLB route ingress traffic to your ALB and have your ALB route traffic to your ec2 instances (Service A).

> Service B -> NLB -> ALB -> Service A

Now you can set a security group to your ALB and allow ingress traffic coming only from the security groups attached your your other ec2 instances (Service B).

Comment: The attacker broke into Service B. Any requests he makes will presumably originate from within Service B and hence have the same source security group(s) as legitimate traffic.

Comment: I agree, the attacker would be able to send requests to Service A from Service B, but only on the allowed ingress ports configured in the ALB's security group. This isn't taking into account what type of traffic flows between these services and what security measures are put in place to authenticate the request.